# Handler should not directly implement the javax.xml.ws.handler.Handler interface

Tags: java, web-services, soap, message-handlers

Before this, I am using `SOAPHandler< SOAPMessageContext >` to handle the data from webservice. The code as follow:

```
public class MyBillSoapMessageHandler implements
    SOAPHandler< SOAPMessageContext >  {

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {

       // This following line something will hit out of memory
       SOAPMessage message = context.getMessage( );

       // some other code continue...
    }
}
```

I tried google it and read something from this link:
[JAX-WS SoapHandler with large messages: OutOfMemoryError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462192/jax-ws-soaphandler-with-large-messages-outofmemoryerror)

Base on my understanding, user `MessageHandlerContext` is better than `SOAPMessageContext`, thus I trying to change it, to become:

```
public class MyBillSoapMessageHandler implements
    MessageHandler< MessageHandlerContext >  {

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(MessageHandlerContext context) {

       //... code here ...//
    }
}
```

However, when I run it, I hit :

> Caused by: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: The com.mybill.ws.camel.MyBillSoapMessageHandler handler should not directly implement the javax.xml.ws.handler.Handler interface.

I am not sure why I get this error. Is there any reason its happen because of my server is not using `MessageHandlerContext`?

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to fix it by using Message Accessor.

My example code as follow:

```
Object accessor = context.get("jaxws.message.accessor");

if (accessor != null) {
                baosInString = accessor.toString();
                }
```

Base on advice from IBM website. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM21151